# Trouble extracting data from html-doc with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to extract data from a page I scraped off the web and I find it to be quite difficult. I tried `soup.get_Text()`, but its no good since it just returns single chars in a row instead of whole string objects.

Extracting the name is easy, because you can access it with the `'b'-tag`, but for example extracting the street ("Am Vogelwäldchen 2") proves to be quite difficult. I could try to assemble the adress from single chars, but this seems overly complicated and I feel there has to be an easier way of doing this. Maybe someone has a better idea. Oh and don't mind the weird function, I returned the soup because I tried different methods on it.

```
import urllib.request
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


#Performs a HTTP-'POST' request, passes it to BeautifulSoup and returns the result
def doRequest(request):
    requestResult = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requestResult)
    return soup

def getContactInfoFromPage(page):
    name = ''
    straße = ''
    plz = ''
    stadt = ''
    telefon = ''
    mail = ''
    url = ''

    data = [
           #'Name',
           #'Straße',
           #'PLZ',
           #'Stadt',
           #'Telefon',
           #'E-Mail',
           #'Homepage'
            ]

    request = urllib.request.Request("http://www.altenheim-adressen.de/schnellsuche/" + page)
    request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8")
    request.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0")
    soup = doRequest(request)

    #Save Name to data structure
    findeName = soup.findAll('b')
    name = findeName[2]
    name = name.string.split('>')

    data.append(name)


    return soup


soup = getContactInfoFromPage("suche2.cfm?id=267a0749e983c7edfeef43ef8e1c7422")

print(soup.getText())
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that when I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rely on the field label and get the [next sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling)'s text.

Making a nice reusable function from this would make it more transparent and easy to use:

```
def get_field_value(soup, field):
    field_label = soup.find('td', text=field + ':')
    return field_label.find_next_sibling('td').get_text(strip=True)
```

Usage:

```
print(get_field_value(soup, 'Name'))  # prints 'AWO-Seniorenzentrum Kenten'
print(get_field_value(soup, 'Land'))  # prints 'Deutschland'
```